# Trying to add buttons dynamically to Activity, Buttons aren't showing up until swapping activity

Tags: android, android-studio

So right now I am trying to create a App for Android. I am already pretty far but I encountered one big issue. To understand it, I'll give some context on what the app does:
It's basically some app where a teacher can add schoolclasses, and in those school classes the teacher can add students.
When clicking the already existing button "add class", the user can input the name of the class, which then gets added as a button with the following method:

```
public void addButton(final String s) {

    if(!existingButtons.contains(s)) {
        Button button = new Button(getContext());
        button.setText(s);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //linearLayout.addView(button, params);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SchoolClassActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("currentClassName", s);
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        existingButtons.add(s);
        ClassesFragment test = new ClassesFragment();

    }
}
```

Now the issue is as follows:
The button does get added upon confirming the input, but it only shows up, when I switch activity or swipe to the right most fragment (3 tabs with Viewpager, left is the page where you can add classes). I would like to know if there is any way to have the button show up, upon confirming the input, so without switching fragments/activities.

Thank you in advance